# GSON disableHtmlEscaping - why GSON HTML-escapes by default in the first place?

Tags: json, gson

I noticed that GSON HTML-escapes `<` and `>` characters and this can be disabled by using `disableHtmlEscaping()` builder configuration method. But my question is - why GSON does HTML-escaping by default? What are the risks of not HTML-escaping anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, the `disableHtmlEscaping()` method tells Gson  not to escape HTML characters such as `<`, `>`, `&`, `=`, and `'`.

An example in which a single quote which cause trouble: rendering unescaped JSON in a `<script/>` tag in an HTML page without using an additional `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tag.

Joel Leitch wrote [a great response to a similar question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-gson/JDHUo9DWyyM/U0kCy7MUcYsJ). Here are the highlights:

> Characters such as  <, >, =, etc. are escaped because if the JSON string evaluated by Gson is embedded in an XHTML page then we do not know what characters are actually wrapping this JSON string. Therefore, if there was an open quote, then the embedded JSON followed by a closing quote then we do not know what will happen.  Maybe if the Gson string contains a abc=123 and there happens to be a "var abc" defined then the embedded the Gson output in the page may cause the abc JavaScript variable to be assigned the value 123.  The same thing can happen with < and > or even &.
>
> As for the whitespace escaping, \t is an escaped character for a tab. Likewise, \n and \r are escape characters for newlines and carriage returns.  Escaping whitespace like this should ensure that any editor will show the proper whitespace (if the editor properly evaluates these escaped characters).

The [Escaper](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Escaper.java?r=597) and [JsonWriter](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/tags/gson-2.2.1/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java#125) classes contain more information on the complete set of characters escaped by Gson.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that thread. With that said - I still see no reasoning for HTML escaping done by default - if anyone wants to transmit JSON via HTML - I see no problem to escape it explicitly in such case.

Comment: This is clearly a security decision. Since JSON is used extensively in HTML defaulting to a more secure state for that usage makes sense. Explicitly turning of the feature gives a chance for someone to consider why the escaping is done and hopefully catch some naive mistakes.
Incidentally I found this thread because I was investigating the security implications of removing the default setting.

Comment: so from security point of view disableHtmlEscaping() is good? and should be always called? is my understanding correct?

Comment: If you're wondering which chars are escaped you can find them in `Escaper.java` file. Currently the list is: `<`, `>`, `&`, `=`, and `\\`. The char / is NOT escaped. See: https://github.com/ybonnel/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Escaper.java